# JavaMail NotTerm not working with Yahoo or Hotmail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I am developing an application that needs to pull specific filtered messages. I also need to be able to exclude certain messages. for instance, a user may want to exclude all message with the subject, which in this case I would create a SubjectTerm, and put it inside a NotTerm. This is returning 0 messages for some reason. while when i ask just for the subject term, it returns the correct message.The specific service i am trying to use this code with are yahoo and hotmail.

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.search.*;

public class imapyahoo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //set the properties for an ssl connection to the imap server.
    java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");

    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
         Store store =  session.getStore();
         System.out.println("connecting....");
         store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", "account", "password");
         System.out.println("connected");
         System.out.println("searching inbox"); 
         Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");

         inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
         //apply the search term.
         SearchTerm st = new NotTerm(new SubjectTerm("dogs"));
         Message[] msgs =inbox.search(st);

         System.out.println(msgs.length);
         System.out.println("done searching");
         //print out the messages
         int i =1;
         for (Message msg : msgs){
             System.out.println(i);
             System.out.println(msg.getSubject());
            i++;
         } 

        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that maybe Yahoo and Hotmail are not supporting this. Searching for items without a specific term is probably more expensive than searching for something that includes a term. I am not sure if this is a programming question (and on topic), or a "what does <provider X> support (or not)", which would be off-topic.

Comment: You can [simplify your program by removing all the socketFactory and ssl settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes); since you're using the "imaps" protocol, all of that is done for you automatically.

Comment: As for the search problem, turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  The debug output will show exactly what the server is returning for your search requests.  Based on what you said, the most likely answer is that the servers are not properly implementing the IMAP spec, and you should report that as a bug to the server vendors.